# Using LINQ to copy data from one table to another one on another server?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have two tables on two different servers.  They're both exactly the same, other than the table on one server has no data.

I want to write a LinqToSql program that will copy the data from one table to the other.  There's only about 7k records.  This is a run-once program.

The error I'm getting is "Ambiguous constructor reference".  It's because when I'm trying to create a new Circuit object to write to the sandbox Circuits table, it doesn't know which one I'm talking about: The Circuit in the Dev context or the Circuit in the Sandbox context.

I guess what I need to do know is if I can use an alias, or something, in order to differentiate between the two Circuits data objects in each context?

Basically, I just need to get all the data in one table to an exact duplicate table on another server.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // set up data contexts
        var circuitsDev = new CircuitsDevDataContext();
        var circuitsSandbox = new CircuitsSandboxDataContext();

        // loop through each record in CircuitsDev data and write it to second table.
        foreach (var circuitData in circuitsDev.Circuits)
        {
            // create new sandbox circuit object
            // This is where error is.
            var circuit = new Circuit(); // <== ambiguous error 

            circuit = circuitData;

            circuitsSandbox.Circuits.InsertOnSubmit(circuit);
        }
        circuitsSandbox.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this tool not for jobs like this. Anyway, use fully qualified names.

Comment: Are you familiar with `BULKCOPY` why not do it that way.. || http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868509/copying-a-row-from-one-table-to-another-using-linq-and-c-sharp

Comment: @DJKRAZE Not familiar at all with SqlBulkCopy.  I had considered using that, but since is just a small amount of data, I thought it would be faster to just write a small program vs trying to figure out how to use SqlBulkCopy.  But, I may end up using it if I can't find a reasonable way to accomplish what I'm trying to do with the small program above.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Circuit classes would be in different namespaces, we can only guess what they are but you would fully qualify the name with the namespace prefixed:

```
var circuit = new SomeNamespace2.Circuit();
```

if declared:

```
namespace SomeNamespace2
{
    public class Circuit {...
```

The issue you will have, since you have two Circuit classes, is you cannot assign one to the other without a conversion.

```
circuit = circuitData;// unable to convert SomeNamespace1.Circuit to SomeNamespace2.Circuit
```

Usually instead you might do it property by property or use something like AutoMapper:

```
circuit.Name = circuitData.Name;
circuit.Location = circuitData.Location;
//...
```

Comment: This worked for me.  I used the namespace for the Sandbox Circuit: `var circuit = new CircuitRebuild2.Circuit();` and the error went away.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
var circuit = new Circuit();
```

to

```
var circuit = new circuitsSandbox.Circuit(); // basically use the full name of the class
```

and then map one property at a time