# c# Entity Framework select into derived child

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, inheritance, select

So I need to select a `Task()` object, with it's `Attachments()` objects, with `Include()`, like this:

```
var tmp = cntx.Tasks.Include( at => at.Attachments ).FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == id );
```

It's working fine, MVC api controller can serialize it to a json, with all of it's Attachmnets listed, basically it's working wonderfully.

Now my problem is, that i need 3 additional string property (for clearer example, I only use +1 string below) in the `Task()`

```
 public class TaskView : DataClasses.Task {
    public string BusinessName { get; set; }
}
```

And those props are not navigational properties for `Task()`, in fact it's from a few other tables. Now I can join up the previous query, with the tables, but I'm not sure how to select the previous fully populated Task object, with all of it's navigational `Attachment()` objects, and cast it to TaskView obj, with the added BusinessName string.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Where does the `BusinessName` come from? Is it from an entity related in any way to `Task`, is it accessible from a navigation property?

Comment: No, it's not accessible as nav property, it come from a legacy table, but i can join() it up. If needed i can rewrite the base classes so it become a nav property, but that would take a while, so if it's possible i want an 'easier' answer something like select( t => new TaskView { task = task.base(), BusinessName = tablename.prop  }). I'm not shure if it's possible, i know i can select 2 object into a third one, but not shure with inherited childs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class TaskView : DataClasses.Task {
    public string BusinessName { get; set; }
    // Create constructor for Task
    public TaskView(DataClasses.Task task)
    {
       // Copy properties here
    }
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
var tmp = cntx.Tasks
  .Include(at => at.Attachments)
  .Where(t => t.Id == id)
  .Select(t=> new TaskView(t) { BusinessName=...})
  .FirstOrDefault();
```

Or you can create a property on TaskView that sets (and possibly get) a Task from TaskView, and just set it in the LINQ query.

Or do this:

```
public class TaskView {
    public string BusinessName { get; set; }
    public DataClasses.Task Task { get; set;}
}
```

Then:

```
var tmp = cntx.Tasks
  .Include(at => at.Attachments)
  .Where(t => t.Id == id)
  .Select(t=> new TaskView { Task=t,BusinessName=...})
  .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: And of course, you could always use one of the answer from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930433/apply-properties-values-from-one-object-to-another-of-the-same-type-automaticall to copy all the properties if you think the properties of Task may change in the future.

Comment: Working like a champ with the linq CopyProperties extension. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

A base class instance cannot be "cast" to a derived class instance. You need to create a new `TaskView` instance and copy all the properties of the source `Task`.

If you can afford, it would be much better to switch to containment rather than inheritance like this

```
public class TaskView
{
    public Task Task { get; set; }
    public string BusinessName { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is a good idea, so i just select the base task object, and the additional property. Trough serializing it to json wont be that nice, because of the additional wrapper object, but i can see it doing the job! If theere will be no answer for my question, i'll accept your workaround as an answer later.

Answer (score 1):

Don't confuse entities with transport layer and their view. Better solution if you create two more classes for transport layer like this:

```
public class TaskDto 
{
  public long Id {get; set;}
  public List<AttachmentsDto> Attachments {get; set;}
}
public class AttachmentsDto 
{
  public long Id {get; set;}
}
```

And two more for view without inheritance like previous. Also you need to create some helper classes for mapping entity to dto and from dto to view.

```
var dtos = cntx.Tasks.Include( at => at.Attachments ).FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == id ).Select(x => new TaskDto 
{
  Id = x.Id,
  Attachments = x.Attachments.Select(y => new AttachmentsDto { Id = y.Id }).ToList()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it with select query, if I understand your question correctly.

Something like:

```
var tmp = from o in cntx.Tasks.Include( at => at.Attachments ) 
were (o.id == id) 
select new TaskView()
{
 //Properties here
 //e.g
 Id = o.Id,
 Attachments = o.Attachments,
 BusinessName = "YourBusinessName"
};
```

Comment: Yes, i need something very similar, except if i hardcoded all the props like prop1 = o1.prop1, then i need to rewrite everything related if i change the Task() base class. So i want exactly this output, but is it possible to select like {  this.base() = task,  BusinessName = sometable.someprop }