# How to copy properties from one .net object to another

Tags: c#, .net

I was trying to find a way to save the object posted to a web service to a database managed by entity.

Instead of copying each property manually, I wanted a way to copy all properties without me doing much code.

Ex: objectFromClient.Copy(objectToDatabase);

This would save me multiple lines of code to copy each property. I liked the suggested code given in this question.

[Apply properties values from one object to another of the same type automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930433/apply-properties-values-from-one-object-to-another-of-the-same-type-automaticall)

However this didnt work on objects tracked by Entity since the Key properties can not be modified in Entity.

I made some amendments to skip those columns which are tagged as EntityKey.

I am not sure if this was a correct approach. Can somebody comment?

```
using System;
using System.Data.Objects.DataClasses;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
/// <summary>
/// A static class for reflection type functions
/// </summary>
public static class Reflection
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Extension for 'Object' that copies the properties to a destination object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">The source.</param>
    /// <param name="destination">The destination.</param>
    public static void CopyProperties(this object source, object destination)
    {
        // If any this null throw an exception
        if (source == null || destination == null)
            throw new Exception("Source or/and Destination Objects are null");
        // Getting the Types of the objects
        Type typeDest = destination.GetType();
        Type typeSrc = source.GetType();
        // Collect all the valid properties to map
        var results = from srcProp in typeSrc.GetProperties()
                      let targetProperty = typeDest.GetProperty(srcProp.Name)
                      where srcProp.CanRead
                      && targetProperty != null
                      && (targetProperty.GetSetMethod(true) != null && !targetProperty.GetSetMethod(true).IsPrivate)
                      && (targetProperty.GetSetMethod().Attributes & MethodAttributes.Static) == 0
                      && targetProperty.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(srcProp.PropertyType)
                      && targetProperty.GetCustomAttributes(false).Where(a => a is EdmScalarPropertyAttribute && ((EdmScalarPropertyAttribute)a).EntityKeyProperty).Count() == 0
                      && srcProp.Name != "EntityKey" 
                      select new { sourceProperty = srcProp, targetProperty = targetProperty };
        //map the properties
        foreach (var props in results)
        {
            //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(props.targetProperty.Name);
            props.targetProperty.SetValue(destination, props.sourceProperty.GetValue(source, null), null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If this code has problems you know of, you may want to post them here. If this code works and you are looking for a review, you might be better off over at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Instead of copying each property manually, I wanted a way to copy all properties without me doing much code.

Have you tried with AutoMapper? Check this [link](http://automapper.org/).

> AutoMapper is a simple little library built to solve a deceptively complex problem - getting rid of code that mapped one object to another.

I use it everywhere, it's quite useful to get rid of code like the one you had to write :)

Comment: It might work for my need. Thanks for pointing me there. 

But this simple extension method is much more clean looking.

Answer (score 5):

This function will copy properties from one object to other.

```
private static Target CopyProperties<Source, Target>(Source source, Target target)
    {
        foreach (var sProp in source.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            bool isMatched = target.GetType().GetProperties().Any(tProp => tProp.Name == sProp.Name && tProp.GetType() == sProp.GetType() && tProp.CanWrite);
            if (isMatched)
            {
                var value = sProp.GetValue(source);
                PropertyInfo propertyInfo = target.GetType().GetProperty(sProp.Name);
                propertyInfo.SetValue(target, value);
            }
        }
        return target;
    }
```