# Pass Array/List Of Variables To Method

Tags: c#, .net, methods

I'm working on a method that dynamically copies variables of the same name and type (not necessarily from the same class).  I don't want to blindly copy everything because an admin of the site has that ability while a user doesn't.  For example, here are some of the event objects:

```
public class Event
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }
    public int Organization { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public int SpotsAvailable { get; set; }
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public int ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public int ApprovedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime ApprovedDate { get; set; }
    public bool AutomaticallyApproved { get; set; }
}
```

What I want to do is have a generic method that only clones the objects I want, ignoring an array of variable names that I want to be left blank or the property's default.  [Based off of this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930433/apply-properties-values-from-one-object-to-another-of-the-same-type-automaticall) I created a method that copies all fields that are named the same and have the same property type and everything works great.  Now I want to add a line (if(ignoreObjects.Contains(srcProp.Name))) that can check if the ignore array contains the current property:

```
 public void Clone(ref object destination, object source, object[] ignoreObjects)
    {
        // Getting the Types of the objects
        Type typeDest = destination.GetType();
        Type typeSrc = source.GetType();

        // Iterate the Properties of the source instance and  
        // populate them from their desination counterparts  
        PropertyInfo[] srcProperties = typeSrc.GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo srcProp in srcProperties)
        {
            if(ignoreObjects.Contains(srcProp.Name))
            {
                continue;
            }
            PropertyInfo targetProperty = typeDest.GetProperty(srcProp.Name);
            if (targetProperty == null)
            {
                continue;
            }
            if (!targetProperty.CanWrite)
            {
                continue;
            }
            if (targetProperty.GetSetMethod(true) != null && targetProperty.GetSetMethod(true).IsPrivate)
            {
                continue;
            }
            if ((targetProperty.GetSetMethod().Attributes & MethodAttributes.Static) != 0)
            {
                continue;
            }
            if (!targetProperty.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(srcProp.PropertyType))
            {
                continue;
            }

            targetProperty.SetValue(destination, srcProp.GetValue(source, null), null);
        }
    }
```

I would ideally call the method above like this:

```
 Clone(ref newEvent, eventInfo, { eventInfo.ApprovedBy, eventInfo.ApprovedDate, eventInfo.Organization, eventInfo.SpotsAvailable } );
```

Where this would copy all event information from "eventInfo" into "newEvent", ignoring the fields ApprovedBy, ApprovedDate, Organization, and SpotsAvailable.

Is it possible to send a list/array of variables to an ignored array?  I can certainly add a "nameof" before each variable to create a string array (ex: nameof(eventInfo.ApprovedBy) ) but I would prefer to just reference the class properties themselves to reduce code.

I've previously used AutoMapper but want to learn if this is possible without any 3rd party tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use object to transfer property name or `PropertyInfo`, you can not pass property value then detect what property it is. You should use `params` keyword:

```
public void Clone(object destination, object source, params String[] ignoreObjects)
```

And call the method:

```
Clone(newEvent, eventInfo, property1, property2, property3, ...);
```

You pass the object then you don't need `ref` keyword.