# Mapping List of sourceObject to List of DestinationObject

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, mapping

I am using the code from [Apply properties values from one object to another of the same type automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930433/apply-properties-values-from-one-object-to-another-of-the-same-type-automaticall)

```
 public static class Reflection
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Extension for 'Object' that copies the properties to a destination object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">The source.</param>
    /// <param name="destination">The destination.</param>
    public static void CopyProperties(this object source, object destination)
    {
        // If any this null throw an exception
        if (source == null || destination == null)
            throw new Exception("Source or/and Destination Objects are null");
        // Getting the Types of the objects
        Type typeDest = destination.GetType();
        Type typeSrc = source.GetType();

        // Iterate the Properties of the source instance and  
        // populate them from their desination counterparts  
        PropertyInfo[] srcProps = typeSrc.GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo srcProp in srcProps)
        {
            if (!srcProp.CanRead)
            {
                continue;
            }
            PropertyInfo targetProperty = typeDest.GetProperty(srcProp.Name);
            if (targetProperty == null)
            {
                continue;
            }
            if (!targetProperty.CanWrite)
            {
                continue;
            }
            if (targetProperty.GetSetMethod(true) != null && targetProperty.GetSetMethod(true).IsPrivate)
            {
                continue;
            }
            if ((targetProperty.GetSetMethod().Attributes & MethodAttributes.Static) != 0)
            {
                continue;
            }
            if (!targetProperty.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(srcProp.PropertyType))
            {
                continue;
            }
            // Passed all tests, lets set the value
            targetProperty.SetValue(destination, srcProp.GetValue(source, null), null);
        }
    }


}
```

That all works great!

What am having trouble trying to figure out is how to create a similar function that takes a List of source and copy to a List of destination and use that to call the code above.

Of course this doesn't work but Something like:

```
 public static void CopyListProperties(this List<object> sourceList, List<object> destinationList)
    {

        foreach (var item in sourceList)
        {
            var destinationObject = new destinationObjectType();
            item.CopyProperties(destinationObject);
            destinationList.Add(destinationObject);
        }

    }
```

Comment: "Pasting code from the Internet into production code is like chewing gum found in the street." - Mike Johnson : Use Generics for default constructor so code woud be like --- CopyListProperties(this List<object> sourceList, List<T> destinationList) where T: new() .... var destinationObject = new T();

Comment: @Alex Krupka That's really helpful.  Thanks!  I don't remember saying it was being used in production code?

Comment: No but the point stands. If you don't understand how code is working you should not be copying it willy nilly into your code. It will come back to bite you.

Comment: @AlexKrupka  Thank you.  I had tried a slew of combinations including the answer in your comment but the one part I was ultimately missing was the new constraint.   The  function that was copied is pretty straight forward reflection.  I was having issues with generic Types.  I do appreciate your help and will update my post with your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Alex on this one.

Here is the function how it should be.

```
public static void CopyListProperties<T>(this List<object> sourceList, List<T> destinationList) where T: new()
        {

            foreach (var item in sourceList)
            {
                var destinationObject = new T();
                item.CopyProperties(destinationObject);
                destinationList.Add(destinationObject);
            }

        }
```