# How to change just last JSON item

Tags: c#, json

I'm building an app for modifying existing json files. I have made all the classes that correspond to my json code. Most of the times I need to copy whole json collection and then just change a few things (like id, index, etc.).

I successfully copy and add whole collection and when I try to change that something in that collection it makes changes in the collection from which I did the copying. Could you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
private void addFlightButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  var originDestinationGroup = jsonObject.search.originDestinationGroup;
  OriginDestinationGroup oDGitem = originDestinationGroup.Last();
  var departureDateGroup = oDGitem.departureDateGroup;
  DepartureDateGroup dDGitem = departureDateGroup.Last();
  var originDestinationOptionRef = dDGitem.originDestinationOptionRef;
  OriginDestinationOptionRef oDORitem = originDestinationOptionRef.Last();

  originDestinationOptionRef.Add(oDORitem);
  char uriNumber = oDORitem.uri[oDORitem.uri.Length - 1];
  string uriString = oDORitem.uri.TrimEnd(oDORitem.uri[oDORitem.uri.Length - 1]);
  int idNumber = Convert.ToInt32(oDORitem.id);
  int indexNumber = oDORitem.index;

  uriNumber++;
  idNumber++;
  indexNumber++;

  OriginDestinationOptionRef oDORitemModify = originDestinationOptionRef.Last();
  oDORitemModify.uri = uriString + uriNumber.ToString();
  oDORitemModify.id = idNumber.ToString();
  oDORitemModify.index = indexNumber;
}
```

**json Response - Not modified:**

```
"search": {
  "originDestinationGroup": [{
        "departureDateGroup": [{
              "originDestinationOptionRef": [{
                  "uri": "option/1",
                  "id": "1",
                  "index": 0
                },
                {
                  "uri": "option/2",
                  "id": "2",
                  "index": 1
                }
              ]
```

**json Response - Modified by my code:**

```
"search": {
  "originDestinationGroup": [{
        "departureDateGroup": [{
              "originDestinationOptionRef": [{
                  "uri": "option/1",
                  "id": "1",
                  "index": 0
                },
                {
                  "uri": "option/3",
                  "id": "3",
                  "index": 2
                },
                {
                  "uri": "option/3",
                  "id": "3",
                  "index": 2
                }
              ]
```

**json Response - How it suppose to be modified:**

```
"search": {
  "originDestinationGroup": [{
        "departureDateGroup": [{
              "originDestinationOptionRef": [{
                  "uri": "/option/1",
                  "id": "1",
                  "index": 0
                },
                {
                  "uri": "option/2",
                  "id": "2",
                  "index": 1
                },
                {
                  "uri": "option/3",
                  "id": "3",
                  "index": 2
                }
              ]
```

**Classes:**

```
public class Search {
  public List<OriginDestinationGroup> originDestinationGroup { get; set; }
}
public class OriginDestinationGroup {
  public List<DepartureDateGroup> departureDateGroup { get; set; }
}
public class DepartureDateGroup {
  public List<OriginDestinationOptionRef> originDestinationOptionRef { get; set; }
}

public class OriginDestinationOptionRef {
  public string uri { get; set; }
  public string id { get; set; }
  public int index { get; set; }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you do some simplier JSON for what it has, what it's supposed to be, and what it actually does? With all the extra numbers/letters in there I can't easily tell what the differences are.

Comment: _"when I try to change that something in that collection it makes changes in the colection from which I did the copying"_ - could be because you're changing the actual reference within the collection. Make a copy of the original - which can be as easy as calling `ToList()` on the collection - and change the copy.

Comment: @gilliduck I changed it. Is this better for you?

Comment: @stuartd Could you please refer to the actual part of the code where I am changing actual reference within the collection. Thank you

Comment: @Adicili now you've simplified the code it's apparent, as per the answers below!

Answer (score 2):

So, you're taking the last item of the collection:

```
OriginDestinationOptionRef oDORitem = originDestinationOptionRef.Last();
```

And adding it to the same collection:

```
originDestinationOptionRef.Add(oDORitem);
```

So the collection now contains **two** pointers to the same object. Then you take the last object in the collection and modify it, but because you've duplicated the reference instead of creating a new object, both the new entry and the one you've copied will change.
So you just need to create a new OriginDestinationOptionRef and add that to the collection, instead of copying an existing one.

Comment: Thank you so much, this answer really helped me. Just one question. Since mine json is much more complicated than this one I put here I really need to copy everything from last item and than just make a few changes. and when I add newItem by your way, that new item is blank and I need to add each item sepparatelly. So how to copy and then modify?

Comment: You can check out the docs for [Object.MemberwiseClone](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone(v=vs.110).aspx) but note that this is a "shallow copy" - so it's fine with properties that are simple types, but if you have properties that are references to _other_ objects you'll need to copy those manually - but there's an example in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

This is where you go wrong:

```
OriginDestinationOptionRef oDORitem = originDestinationOptionRef.Last();
originDestinationOptionRef.Add(oDORitem);
```

This code gets the last item from the list and then adds a new reference to that **very same object** to the very same list. So the list becomes longer by 1 entry, but the last two entries are now pointing to the same object in memory (the original object, which you then proceed to change).

To solve this, create a new `OriginDestinationOptionRef` object:

```
var newItem = new OriginDestinationOptionRef();
originDestinationOptionRef.Add(newItem);
```

Then use your existing logic to set the properties of `newItem`.

Comment: Thank you so much, this answer really helped me. Just one question. Since mine json is much more complicated than this one I put here I really need to copy everything from last item and than just make a few changes. and when I add newItem by your way, that new item is blank and I need to add each item sepparatelly. So how to copy and then modify?

Comment: There is no way around copying all properties from the source to the target, one way or another. See e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/930433/1220550 for guidance on some possible approaches that can be useful in more scenarios than just this one.