# Copy only changed and not null properties between two classes to a third one in C#

Tags: c#, class, mapping

I'll try to explain what I want to do:

If I have this class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string foo { get; set; }
    public string bar { get; set; }
    public string age { get; set; }
}
```

And I instantiate three classes in three different objects like this:

```
void Main()
{
    var myA = new MyClass() { foo = "foo", bar = "bar", age = "age" };
    var myB = new MyClass() { foo = "foo", bar = "change" };
    var myC = new MyClass() { foo = "xxx", bar = "yyy", age = "zzz" };

    //I want myC with this values: foo = "xxx", bar = "change", age = "zzz"
}
```

So that I want that only the different not null properties from `myA`comparing `myB` be copied to `myC`. Only `myB.bar` is a not null different property comparing `myA.bar` and this should be the only change copied to `myC.bar`

How I should I do that? Using Automapper? Or maybe using System.Reflection? Which is the easiest and best practice to do this?

**EDIT**
I'm now using a modified version of this solution:
[Apply properties values from one object to another of the same type automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930433/apply-properties-values-from-one-object-to-another-of-the-same-type-automaticall)

Passing the `myC` object like a parameter but I'm guessing if this is the best solution

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've provided the simplest approach would be to add an instance method to `MyClass` to do the copy.

Something like:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string foo { get; set; }
    public string bar { get; set; }
    public string age { get; set; }

    public MyClass DiffCopy(MyClass diff)
    {
        MyClass copy = new MyClass
        {
            foo = this.foo != diff.foo ? this.foo : null,
            bar = this.bar != diff.bar ? this.bar : null,
            age = this.age != diff.age ? this.age : null,
        };

        return copy;
    }
}
```

Comment: The "copy" class already exists, it could be a parameter. But I think something more generic like an extension could be better